# How can I use "imgtovol" with nodejs

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, computer-vision

I looked at this link https://github.com/karpathy/convnetjs .In CNN example there is `var x = convnetjs.img_to_vol(document.getElementById('some_image'))` 
code but in node js there isn't document.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, that example is meant to be used on a web browser, have you tried to read a image file to a byte array and send it to convnetjs?

Something like this:

```
    fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile('image.jpg', function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var x = convnetjs.img_to_vol(data)
    });
```